# Animated gif background lagging on Ipad any work around?

Tags: html, css

I am using method 'CSS-Only Technique #2' from the site below, but with an animated GIF:

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

The GIF is relatively small (around 500KB) but it's causing my site to lag a lot when scrolling down / upwards. The `div` containing my text is actually loading / refreshing as if lazy-loading (I am not using lazyload plugin) when scrolling fast.

It takes a while for the my paragraph to load, and in the meantime the background animated gif freezes.

Is there any workaround for this?

The issue above disappears when the animated gif is replaced with a static image -- I'm quite sure it's the animated gif causing the lag here.

Anyway seems like this issue is only for iPad.

Comment: It probably has to do with the repainting of the scene by the GPU.. Does it help at all if you add a CSS3 transform to it (like `-webkit-transform: rotateX(0);`)?

Comment: woah! Thanks somethinghere ! animated gif not freezing any more but div is "lazyloading" even without the plugin. Even when scrolling up, i have to wait for my paragraph that appeared earlier to appear again(this is not happening on my  desktop)

Comment: Can anyone pls explain me how adding CSS3 transform solved the problem? :) thanks in advance.

Comment: Ben, Thanks for editting

Comment: @HarshalGajjar Luke Roberts has got the right answer down below. In short, it hands it off to the chips dedicated for graphics. Don't overuse it though, as it would just overtax the other chip and slowdown would return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By applying a "3D" transform to an element it tricks a device into using it's inbuilt GPU as opposed to the CPU to handle rendering which is better for performance because GPU's are used to handle playing games etc.

You can get a good idea of this by watching Paul Irish's video which goes super in depth on this stuff.

found [here](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/)

Answer (score 4):

As Luke Roberts mentioned (based on the comment I made to the original post), adding a transform to an element will allow its rendering to be smoother. Don't overuse it (hand off too much to the GPU and it gets bottlenecked just like the CPU), but applying it sporadically allows you to hand off taxing things to the renderer directly instead of parsing it through the DOM rendering. So the solution is simple, certainly if you want it limited to the iPad, when using the -webkit- prefix already limits it quite a bit:

```
.gif {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0);
}
```

You can limit it even more by using

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
```

to limit it to retina ipads. Non-retina ipads won't be able to run this smoothly anyway. I think.

Also, the paragraph problem you mentioned in the comments might be because the paragraph isn't rendered by the GPU. Be sure not to overuse it, but you could try to get your content div into the renderer as well. If I'm correct every element is handed of separately, but is treated as one layer. As long as you just hand of the surrounding div, it should't take too much GPU. Just don;t apply it universally and see if it helps.